# Downloading with curl when site uses cookies

Tags: curl, https, session-cookies

I was able to download the data ( json response) from the below URL for a while via curl on Windows.

curl.exe https://www.theocc.com/mdapi/series-search?symbol_type=U&symbol=AA

or

curl.exe https://www.theocc.com/mdapi/series-search?symbol_type=U&symbol=AA&exchange=

But recently it stopped working and instead getting an error html that says

"Enable JavaScript and cookies to continue"

Is there a way I can make this work again?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I spent a few hours on this one because I am interested in the Cloudflare 403 Forbidden response.  This has become a big problem for curl.  And now it is your problem too.

I basically got two different responses. One from Win 10 curl (cmd) using 3 different requests.

The PHP only got a 403 Forbidden HTTP Status response.
This likely do to my curl TLS certificates, or lack of them.

I believe Win 10 curl is setup with the same CA as Edge.

Cloudflare often rejects curl requests.  Cloudflare profiles Browsers TLS handshaking. If the handshaking does not match the User Agent it does not pass the request to the Host. Instead it returns a 403 Forbidden.

There is no shortage of information if you search for "Fix Cloudflare 403 Forbidden"

I believe the problem you have is due to Cloudflare.

I do not think it is related to JavaScript.

I Disabled JavaScript on both Edge and Firefox and still got the JSON.

Response Header:

```
HTTP/2 200 OK
date: Sat, 19 Nov 2022 01:18:10 GMT
content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
content-encoding: gzip
vary: Accept-Encoding
request-context: appId=cid-v1:30c6c72c-1099-4721-b73f-c69b90d8ae95
strict-transport-security: max-age=2592000; includeSubDomains; preload
cf-cache-status: DYNAMIC
set-cookie: __cf_bm=4i3UCcOc3ABOk_qatlAieY0OkXfECjDOJG_G_Nm.ex0-1668820690-0-Acph3yaZ3B2kSsPbygIqBJubZSuDb+OUkgmIMDycJ4JyRBJq8gv4QCJEirVC9o6WedMi/p6xrc0z+xdBS5J4s4c=; path=/; expires=Sat, 19-Nov-22 01:48:10 GMT; domain=.theocc.com; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None
server: cloudflare
cf-ray: 76c51c3f3a952209-MIA
X-Firefox-Spdy: h2
```

The JSON in the response body:

```
{"Content":[{"Date":"2022-11-18T00:00:00Z","Results":[{"ProdSymbolId":"AA    ","ExprDate":1668751200000000,"StrikePriceIntg":17,"StrikePriceFrac":500,"CallTickSymbolId":"C","PutTickSymbolId":"P","CallOpenInt":0,"PutOpenInt":5950,"PosLimit":25000000,"SecuId":"AA    ","CusiId":null,"Name":"Alcoa Corporation                                 ","OnnGrp":"EU","StrPriceFrac":null,"StrikePriceFracStr":"500"},{"ProdSymbolId":"AA    ","ExprDate":1668751200000000,"StrikePriceIntg":20,"StrikePriceFrac":0,"CallTickSymbolId":"C","PutTickSymbolId":"P","CallOpenInt":0,"PutOpenInt":1553,"PosLimit":25000000,"SecuId":"AA    ","CusiId":null,"Name":"Alcoa Corporation                                 ","OnnGrp":"EU","StrPriceFrac":null,"StrikePriceFracStr":"000"},{"ProdSymbolId":"AA    ","ExprDate":1668751200000000,"StrikePriceIntg":22,"StrikePriceFrac":500,"CallTickSymbolId":"C","PutTickSymbolId":"P","CallOpenInt":25,"PutOpenInt":3145,"PosLimit":25000000,"SecuId":"AA    ","CusiId":null,"Name":"Alcoa Corporation                                 ","OnnGrp":"EU","StrPriceFrac":null,"StrikePriceFracStr":"500"},{"ProdSymbolId":"AA    ","ExprDate":1668751200000000,"StrikePriceIntg":25,"StrikePriceFrac":0,"CallTickSymbolId":"C","PutTickSymbolId":"P","CallOpenInt":115,"PutOpenInt":2714,"PosLimit":25000000,"SecuId":"AA    ","CusiId":null,"Name":"Alcoa Corporation                                 ","OnnGrp":"EU","StrPriceFrac":null,"StrikePriceFracStr":"000"},{"ProdSymbolId":"AA    ","ExprDate":1668751200000000,"StrikePriceIntg":30,"StrikePriceFrac":0,"CallTickSymbolId":"C","PutTickSymbolId":"P","CallOpenInt":263,"PutOpenInt":4645,"PosLimit":25000000,"SecuId":"AA    ","CusiId":null,"Name":"Alcoa Corporation                                 ","OnnGrp":"EU","StrPriceFrac":null,"StrikePriceFracStr":"000"},{"ProdSymbolId":"AA    ","ExprDate":1668751200000000,"StrikePriceIntg":32,"StrikePriceFrac":0,"CallTickSymbolId":"C","PutTickSymbolId":"P","CallOpenInt":21,"PutOpenInt":396,"PosLimit":25000000,"SecuId":"AA    ","CusiId":null,"Name":"Alcoa Corporation                                 ","OnnGrp":"EU","StrPriceFrac":null,"StrikePriceFracStr":"000"},{"ProdSymbolId":"AA    ","ExprDate":1668751200000000,"StrikePriceIntg":33,"StrikePriceFrac":0,"CallTickSymbolId":"C","PutTickSymbolId":"P","CallOpenInt":44,"PutOpenInt":409,"PosLimit":25000000,"SecuId":"AA    ","CusiId":null,"Name":"Alcoa Corporation                                 ","OnnGrp":"EU","StrPriceFrac":null,"StrikePriceFracStr":"000"},{"ProdSymbolId":"AA    ","ExprDate":1668751200000000,"StrikePriceIntg":34,"StrikePriceFrac":0,"CallTickSymbolId":"C","PutTickSymbolId":"P","CallOpenInt":28,"PutOpenInt":145,"PosLimit":25000000,"SecuId":"AA    ","CusiId":null,"Name":"Alcoa Corporation                                 ","OnnGrp":"EU","StrPriceFrac":null,"StrikePriceFracStr":"000"},{"ProdSymbolId":"AA    ","ExprDate":1668751200000000,"StrikePriceIntg":35,"StrikePriceFrac":0,"CallTickSymbolId":"C","PutTickSymbolId":"P","CallOpenInt":271,"PutOpenInt":3760,"PosLimit":25000000,"SecuId":"AA    ","CusiId":null,"Name":"Alcoa Corporation                                 ","OnnGrp":"EU","StrPriceFrac":null,"StrikePriceFracStr":"000"},{"ProdSymbolId":"AA    ","ExprDate":1668751200000000,"StrikePriceIntg":35,"StrikePriceFrac":500,"CallTickSymbolId":"C","PutTickSymbolId":"P","CallOpenInt":30,"PutOpenInt":101,"PosLimit":25000000,"SecuId":"AA    ","CusiId":null,"Name":"Alcoa Corporation                                 ","OnnGrp":"EU","StrPriceFrac":null,"StrikePriceFracStr":"500"},{"ProdSymbolId":"AA
```

---

---

A Win 10 curl the URL must be in double quotes and
sometimes the query sting `&` must be escaped `\&`

I tried these requests in a Win 10 cmd window  with escaped `\&`:

```
curl "https://www.theocc.com/mdapi/series-search?symbol_type=U\&symbol=AA" 

curl "https://www.theocc.com/mdapi/series-search?symbol_type=U\&symbol=AA" -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:107.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/107.0' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5'  -H 'DNT: 1' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Cookie: ARRAffinity=50cf07c4923930f3ead4232e638b6657fb662613b8f01df70fb38ac353b8e3d6; ARRAffinitySameSite=50cf07c4923930f3ead4232e638b6657fb662613b8f01df70fb38ac353b8e3d6' -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' -H 'Sec-Fetch-Dest: document' -H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate' -H 'Sec-Fetch-Site: none' -H 'Sec-Fetch-User: ?1'

curl "https://www.theocc.com/mdapi/series-search?symbol_type=U&symbol=AA" ^
  -H "authority: www.theocc.com" ^
  -H "accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9" ^
  -H "accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9" ^
  -H "cache-control: max-age=0" ^
  -H "cookie: ARRAffinity=50cf07c4923930f3ead4232e638b6657fb662613b8f01df70fb38ac353b8e3d6; ARRAffinitySameSite=50cf07c4923930f3ead4232e638b6657fb662613b8f01df70fb38ac353b8e3d6; __cf_bm=FS_Oi_E3bPH7QBQUW.XzcyQDP6PFkL8RHPbA0qbdj8I-1668824712-0-AfSfUDI6XgJiQRrzEHCihbO2DP1VUL1Y9fkmzArjKYqZ356bWDu0eSuUlxkJoAc+N7nVyOBw4itGMsGRSuYf6oc=" ^
  -H "sec-fetch-dest: document" ^
  -H "sec-fetch-mode: navigate" ^
  -H "sec-fetch-site: none" ^
  -H "sec-fetch-user: ?1" ^
  -H "upgrade-insecure-requests: 1" ^
  -H "user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows Phone 8.0; Trident/6.0; IEMobile/10.0; ARM; Touch; NOKIA; Lumia 920) UCBrowser/10.1.0.563 Mobile" ^
  --compressed
```

The second request cam from Firefox Network as Copy as curl (POSIX)
The third request was copied from Edge Network Tool as curl (cmd).  Yet it would not work until I removed all `^cr/lf`

[image]

---

---

The Win 10 curl response, same for all three requests.
The response below came from Cloudflare.
Based on the response headers I do not believe these requests were passed to the Host `theocc.com`.

Response Header

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Date: Sat, 19 Nov 2022 04:17:29 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: close
CF-Chl-Bypass: 1
Referrer-Policy: same-origin
Permissions-Policy: accelerometer=(),autoplay=(),camera=(),clipboard-read=(),clipboard-write=(),fullscreen=(),geolocation=(),gyroscope=(),hid=(),interest-cohort=(),magnetometer=(),microphone=(),payment=(),publickey-credentials-get=(),screen-wake-lock=(),serial=(),sync-xhr=(),usb=()
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Set-Cookie: __cf_bm=jNH8U9rGVke8A3M9NVoGyM_54P4yqbD6GUdBex2U9as-1668831449-0-Aajlm5as+JsCCdzuStWeD6FNiZE6Q7BqSSGV+axg1GOcbz3CREOYW+gy0pq0iJpVVZ5HRo2RQA3AQaaFBjNnIsk=; path=/; expires=Sat, 19-Nov-22 04:47:29 GMT; domain=.theocc.com; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None
Server: cloudflare
CF-RAY: 76c622f05c20d9d1-MIA
```

Response HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <title>Just a moment...</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <link href="/cdn-cgi/styles/challenges.css" rel="stylesheet">


</head>
<body class="no-js">
    <div class="main-wrapper" role="main">
    <div class="main-content">
        <h1 class="zone-name-title h1">
            <img class="heading-favicon" src="/favicon.ico"
                 onerror="this.onerror=null;this.parentNode.removeChild(this)">
            www.theocc.com
        </h1>
        <h2 class="h2" id="challenge-running">
            Checking if the site connection is secure
        </h2>
        <noscript>
            <div id="challenge-error-title">
                <div class="h2">
                    <span class="icon-wrapper">
                        <div class="heading-icon warning-icon"></div>
                    </span>
                    <span id="challenge-error-text">
                        Enable JavaScript and cookies to continue
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </noscript>
        <div id="trk_jschal_js" style="display:none;background-image:url('/cdn-cgi/images/trace/managed/nojs/transparent.gif?ray=76c5e617baf0221a')"></div>
        <div id="challenge-body-text" class="core-msg spacer">
            www.theocc.com needs to review the security of your connection before proceeding.
        </div>
        <form id="challenge-form" action="/mdapi/series-search?symbol_type=U\&amp;symbol=AA&amp;__cf_chl_f_tk=kUJFHohnkrGLP_aT8f5l1edyZE38Iuvbqeguf9EaPyM-1668828957-0-gaNycGzNCH0" method="POST" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
            <input type="hidden" name="md" value="C_LKeu2P5NrY0aR4BxvKBGqNiMKJ1potyy02pUTruns-1668828957-0-ASvIMrC-30PITC58EAtdhq56Jx7fME4EOUOUE-FMk5FBMP_d7Pfr7XFI_Qr6SAVlPAQCGA9_b9beL_agWaV1I44NJRLSb5IkRQ3E6icwIe8Eq7QVMQWYJ-KlvST_JI7znFj_MeqOMA50UlrgSYomFz8TuMTnjbbiiYo9FziI0gyhbYedZ0BtSiUakd9eMeV54maAR1UqybWW52Lj1qpMUZtAes6YaVvVNcjVLtBtjt5Dbspqa8XsoRwpk11VO5GnlLoz4uSqh-laMjyd6zOas7YCD7Qzs05AGIBGKLuPZ3xeyq43ZS0zcGLkxsxwgbF1IWdBz8br6tVuO6YFvY5qSsEeXvymMXbCltsj8tqKDb-XoCbfyFF_Gb33LwFmxYudOqrvZ-2miy-BbZAGrSRGe7_nNDfKf94f_ZRrpSu25VvNhvni46u1AUa4v4wy7O6ujeT9JHpwem_0Y2RUw5QJywl8ZXSFf9yGkYq9us8Dwbvkhcis7ovToZv3eP2Gf0MKjgSIj0twbMVIguUCrluO5vVhdzWu1HJfaZI0htq0Rn8ZWD9g0XF5amnaWs80iXocIIsJKPEhHDuh5jpNOH0suaXfZm7waukxfDxRUURM6Kg4BEEaJrNH0ZAsLLvaDfaQ-XCgr_s2VFRdLEQHMEScQ76P271i_MfhA23Xv0uSlLwPRjcnrrYhhfAOoYXMxUqMBjntLp52kLxAgBlV7fD4l8xe-JNpKYWaqi5IXQKLn87mG3XV4SCeeysfvhT26n4CHWXlgroGtv6AwcGtIR6Hkvg">
            <input type="hidden" name="r" value="NEE5A4XvbVzMlgGmfv94hrNQy8HlFwlN9MvsAnrBqEc-1668828957-0-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">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    (function(){
        window._cf_chl_opt={
            cvId: '2',
            cType: 'managed',
            cNounce: '32555',
            cRay: '76c5e617baf0221a',
            cHash: '7592d66e2323e80',
            cUPMDTk: "\/mdapi\/series-search?symbol_type=U\\&symbol=AA&__cf_chl_tk=kUJFHohnkrGLP_aT8f5l1edyZE38Iuvbqeguf9EaPyM-1668828957-0-gaNycGzNCH0",
            cFPWv: 'b',
            cTTimeMs: '1000',
            cTplV: 4,
            cTplB: 'cf',
            cRq: {
                ru: 'aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cudGhlb2NjLmNvbS9tZGFwaS9zZXJpZXMtc2VhcmNoP3N5bWJvbF90eXBlPVVcJnN5bWJvbD1BQQ==',
                ra: 'TW96aWxsYS81LjAgKFdpbmRvd3MgTlQgMTAuMDsgV2luNjQ7IHg2NCkgQXBwbGVXZWJLaXQvNTM3LjM2IChLSFRNTCwgbGlrZSBHZWNrbykgQ2hyb21lLzEwNy4wLjAuMCBTYWZhcmkvNTM3LjM2IEVkZy8xMDcuMC4xNDE4LjQy',
                rm: 'R0VU',
                d: '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',
                t: 'MTY2ODgyODk1Ny40MDQwMDA=',
                m: '/aGrMgSdZO6ogXdUQEEOQsDgNn+UAxlig04+B+a9YQY=',
                i1: 'wffO0nID3av5tavW3mXdtA==',
                i2: 'eIr4tQZjzWSBg3EFfM1UhA==',
                zh: 'rjV/vZpjqak/inbeUs7nHF3bR1cMk2CD6n2tHAx8WJg=',
                uh: 'p19SMC98WhDwvsQz+Kqkj/EMDYzdbqDnaATK9trmhK0=',
                hh: 'rTcMqa1eOqviz82idTtNQqeGJGdhBGQmQRzkYbDEzA4=',
            }
        };
        var trkjs = document.createElement('img');
        trkjs.setAttribute('src', '/cdn-cgi/images/trace/managed/js/transparent.gif?ray=76c5e617baf0221a');
        trkjs.setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
        document.body.appendChild(trkjs);
        var cpo = document.createElement('script');
        cpo.src = '/cdn-cgi/challenge-platform/h/b/orchestrate/managed/v1?ray=76c5e617baf0221a';
        window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUHash = location.hash === '' && location.href.indexOf('#') !== -1 ? '#' : location.hash;
        window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUQuery = location.search === '' && location.href.slice(0, -window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUHash.length).indexOf('?') !== -1 ? '?' : location.search;
        if (window.history && window.history.replaceState) {
            var ogU = location.pathname + window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUQuery + window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUHash;
            history.replaceState(null, null, "\/mdapi\/series-search?symbol_type=U\\&symbol=AA&__cf_chl_rt_tk=kUJFHohnkrGLP_aT8f5l1edyZE38Iuvbqeguf9EaPyM-1668828957-0-gaNycGzNCH0" + window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUHash);
            cpo.onload = function() {
                history.replaceState(null, null, ogU);
            };
        }
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(cpo);
    }());
</script>


    <div class="footer" role="contentinfo">
        <div class="footer-inner">
            <div class="clearfix diagnostic-wrapper">
                <div class="ray-id">Ray ID: <code>76c5e617baf0221a</code></div>
            </div>
            <div class="text-center">Performance &amp; security by <a rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.cloudflare.com?utm_source=challenge&utm_campaign=m" target="_blank">Cloudflare</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I also used PHP's curl.

```
$headers = array();
//$headers[] = 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:107.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/107.0';
$headers[] = 'User-Agent: MOT-V9mm/00.62 UP.Browser/6.2.3.4.c.1.123 (GUI) MMP/2.0';
$headers[] = 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8';
$headers[] = 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5';
$headers[] = 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br';
$headers[] = 'DNT: 1';
$headers[] = 'Connection: keep-alive';
$headers[] = 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1';
$headers[] = 'Sec-Fetch-Dest: document';
$headers[] = 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate';
$headers[] = 'Sec-Fetch-Site: none';
$headers[] = 'Sec-Fetch-User: ?1';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.theocc.com/mdapi/series-search?symbol_type=U&symbol=AA');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING,"");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING,"");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch,  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
echo "Response: $response\n";
echo "\nheader out: \n" . curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT);
echo "curl Error: \n" . curl_error($ch);
echo "\n\ncurl_get_info:\n";
var_export(curl_getinfo($ch));
```

The above PHP code returned no response header or body, just a 403 Forbidden HTTP Status

```
Response: 

header out: 
GET /mdapi/series-search?symbol_type=U&symbol=AA HTTP/2
Host: www.theocc.com
user-agent: MOT-V9mm/00.62 UP.Browser/6.2.3.4.c.1.123 (GUI) MMP/2.0
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.5
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
dnt: 1
connection: keep-alive
upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
sec-fetch-dest: document
sec-fetch-mode: navigate
sec-fetch-site: none
sec-fetch-user: ?1

curl Error: 
The requested URL returned error: 403

curl_get_info:
array (
  'url' => 'https://www.theocc.com/mdapi/series-search?symbol_type=U&symbol=AA',
  'content_type' => 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
  'http_code' => 403,
  'header_size' => 954,
  'request_size' => 470,
  'filetime' => -1,
  'ssl_verify_result' => 20,
  'redirect_count' => 0,
  'total_time' => 0.082475,
  'namelookup_time' => 0.000513,
  'connect_time' => 0.016717,
  'pretransfer_time' => 0.039101,
  'size_upload' => 0.0,
  'size_download' => 0.0,
  'speed_download' => 0.0,
  'speed_upload' => 0.0,
  'download_content_length' => -1.0,
  'upload_content_length' => 0.0,
  'starttransfer_time' => 0.0824,
  'redirect_time' => 0.0,
  'redirect_url' => '',
  'primary_ip' => '2606:4700:90:0:3d7d:1d0b:b681:7270',
  'certinfo' => 
  array (
  ),
  'primary_port' => 443,
  'local_ip' => '2604:4500:0:8d:ec4:7aff:fe76:281a',
  'local_port' => 46564,
  'request_header' => 'GET /mdapi/series-search?symbol_type=U&symbol=AA HTTP/2
Host: www.theocc.com
user-agent: MOT-V9mm/00.62 UP.Browser/6.2.3.4.c.1.123 (GUI) MMP/2.0
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.5
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
dnt: 1
connection: keep-alive
upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
sec-fetch-dest: document
sec-fetch-mode: navigate
sec-fetch-site: none
sec-fetch-user: ?1

',
)
```

I do not know if this helps, but this URL works in Win 10 cmd.
And works in PHP
NOTE:  The escaped `\&` did not work on this URL.

This is not hosted on Cloudflare.

```
>curl "https://marketdata.theocc.com/series-search?symbolType=U&symbol=AA"
```

Response:

```
                Series/contract         Strike                  Open Interest
ProductSymbol   year    Month   Day     Integer Dec     C/P     Call    Put     Position Limit
AA              2022    11      18      17      500     C P     0       5950    25000000
AA              2022    11      18      20      000     C P     0       1553    25000000
AA              2022    11      18      22      500     C P     0       3145    25000000
AA              2022    11      18      25      000     C P     0       2714    25000000
AA              2022    11      18      30      000     C P     0       4645    25000000
AA              2022    11      18      32      000     C P     0       396     25000000
AA              2022    11      18      33      000     C P     0       409     25000000
AA              2022    11      18      34      000     C P     0       145     25000000
AA              2022    11      18      35      000     C P     0       3760    25000000
AA              2022    11      18      35      500     C P     0       101     25000000
AA              2022    11      18      36      000     C P     0       211     25000000
AA              2022    11      18      36      500     C P     0       163     25000000
```

Comment: Thx for the effort, the new URL you posted is great, it returns data in a diff format but I can use.

Comment: Cloudefare is giving a challenge, which can only be answered if client can handle js. from their doc. ​​ "JS challenge
With a JS challenge, Cloudflare presents challenge page that requires no interaction from a visitor, but rather JavaScript processing by their browser."

Comment: @MadhaviD That makes perfect sense.  What I cannot grasp about that is the JSON is returned even when the Browser's JS is disabled.  It is no secret that Cloudflare has profiled many User Agents so they do not need to use the easily spoofed User Agent header.  I would like to see Firefox add curl capabilities to their Browser.

Answer (score -1):

To answer the title of your question:

```
curl -b cookies -c cookies <URL>
```

but if javascript is mandatory, it will fail. Curl have no javascript capabilities

Comment: This didn't work. Got this response <h2 class="h2" id="challenge-running">
            Checking if the site connection is secure
        </h2>
        <noscript>
            <div id="challenge-error-title">
                <div class="h2">
                    <span class="icon-wrapper">
                        <div class="heading-icon warning-icon"></div>
                    </span>
                    <span id="challenge-error-text">
                        Enable JavaScript and cookies to continue
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>